# How could I determine the number of unique floating-point numbers in between two arbitrary a and b?

Tags: floating-point, double

How could I  write a generic C routine num(a,b) that calculates the number of floating-point number in between a and b? Assume both a and b are of type `double`.

For example, `num(0,1e-17)` should return the number of doubles in between `0` and `1e-17`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this

Comment: This seems pretty broad. Do you mean the number of unique values that could be represented using the type based on the precision available with the number of bits used for a double?

Comment: If you give an example of two values a, b, and the result you expect, that would help.

Comment: @EdHeal I am doing this for fun and for understanding more deeply of the floating-point format.

Comment: There are a variety of representations. Indeed the processor or its registers may have a different representation to what is stored I  main memory

Comment: @EdHeal You ask this question in comments a lot (“Why would anyone want to do that?”, …). Have you ever found it to be productive?

Comment: @PascalCuoq - yes - interesting to discover the motivation behind some of the questions

Comment: Do you consider `0.0` and `-0.0` to be 2 different FP numbers (they have different bit patterns) or do you consider them the same as they have the same _value_?   IMO, they are different for the purposes on this post, but wanted to know your goal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer assumes in addition to “both `a` and `b` are of type `double`” that `double` maps to IEEE 754 double-precision, and that its representation, accessed as a `uint64_t` integer, is interpreted with the same endianness as floating-point numbers. This is the case on mainstream compilation platforms.

Under these hypotheses, the representations of positive and negative floating-point numbers are consecutive 64-bit integers. So in order to compute how many numbers there are between two floating-point numbers of the same sign, compute the number of integers between their representations interpreted as 64-bit unsigned integers:

```
double a, b;
…
uint64_t a1, b1;
memcpy(&a1, &a, 8);
memcpy(&b1, &b, 8);
int64_t d = a1 - b1;
if (d<0) d = -d;
d++; /* account for both a and b e.g. if a==b, they enclose one FP number */
```

If the floating-point numbers do not have the same sign, compute the number of floating-point numbers between the negative one and `-0.0`, and the number of floating-point numbers between the positive one and `+0.0`, using the above method. Then sum these two parts.

Comment: Assuming the endian is the same for the `int64_t`  and `double` as it usual is, this is a nifty piece of code although I would change `if (d<0)` to `if (signbit(d))`

Comment: @chux I will add the caveat about endianness. About `signbit`, I'm not sure how to use it: `d` is an integer above.

Comment: Oops. Was thinking `d` was `double`.  Dis-regard `signbit()` idea.  Do suggest using `uint64_t` though rather than `int64_t` to handle `uint64_t zell_diff(-DBL_MAX, DBL_MAX)`;

Comment: @chux it may look that there is a risk of overflow in `int64_t d = a1 - b1;` but as long as `a1` and `b1` are finite floating-point numbers of the same sign, it should not happen. They can even be infinite. The important thing is that neither is NaN.

Comment: @chux subtracting representations does not work if `a` and `b` (and thus `a1` and b1`) have different signs. As long as they have the same sign, it is fine to use `int64_t` as destination for the subtraction, and it is nicer than to have to worry what sign the floating-point numbers were **and** in which order they were passed.

Answer (score 3):

[@Pascal Cuoq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39258323/2410359) well explains the lmitations of `double` representaiton, endian, etc.

Below is a variation on how to extract a sequence number for the `double`.

```
unsigned long long SequenceNumber(double d) {
  assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(uint64_t));
  union {
    double d;
    uint64_t u64;
    int64_t i64;
  } x = {d};
  uint64_t y;

  if (x.i64 < 0) {
    y = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF - x.u64;
  } else {
    y = 0x8000000000000000 + x.u64;
  }
  return y;
}

unsigned long long SequenceDiff(double a, double b) {
  unsigned long long sna = SequenceNumber(a);
  unsigned long long snb = SequenceNumber(b);
  return sna > snb ? sna - snb : snb - sna;
}
```